# Switch Branches on Multiple Subdirectories

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have many modules in a project folder.

```
/MyProject
/MyProject/ModuleA
/MyProject/ModuleB
/MyProject/ModuleC
...
```

Is there a command in IntelliJ or on the command line that switches all my modules to a particular branch?  A shortcut for this:

```
cd ModuleA
git checkout master
cd ..
cd ModuleB
git checkout master
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git submodule foreach` to execute an arbitrary shell command for each defined submodule. To checkout `master` in every submodule, you can run:

```
$ git submodule foreach 'git checkout master'
```

If you have submodules in the submodules, you should add `--recursive`.

Note that the modules need to be checked out in order to use `git submodule foreach`. To make sure all submodules are checked out, run:

```
$ git submodule update --init
```

It does not matter what version is checked out, but the submodule must be initialized.